# ng serve --prod does not include the css from component

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular2-cli

When I serve the app for production using `ng serve --prod`, the compiled version (bundled CSS) does not include the CSS specific to component. I.e. when I look for the classes and definition provided in the styles.scss I was able to see it, but when I tried to find the classes and definitions specified in the scss file for component, they were not present in bundle css. There were no errors.

Comment: Because your files are bundled, minified and encapsulated. Inspect your HTML elements directly to see their styles.

Comment: @trichetriche: Thanks for replying.  I did inspect the elements. In case of normal ng serve when I inspect the span I see valid CSS in the style section(i.e. the definition of the classes is applied)  but in ng serve --prod the class definition is not there. Would have posted images of inspection but I do not have enough points yet to do that.